# MySQL won't start after changin my.cf

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, sql-mode

I'm working on a website and I'm getting this MySQL error:

> "(...) this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (...)"

I've looked for an answer and I realized I had to change the sql_mode of my MySQL. So I've added the following line to /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

But now when I executed `sudo service mysql restart` it takes a really long time and then shows this message:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So now I removed that line and I have to execute the command by hand everytime I boot my PC.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, I applied the changes in the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` file and it worked, finally.

Comment: This solution helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove sql mode in my.cnf and restart the mysql service then execute the bellow query.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

Comment: I'm already doing that, but I have to do it everytime I boot my PC. I'm looking for a definitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing my.cf directly, you need to remove the quotes.

`sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Referenced here and working for me: https://gist.github.com/cucxabeng/938b55b3e8b8f1bf230edbf043254189