# Error while setting value ''STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20. mySQL upgrade failed during the upgrade.
After the upgrade, I again tried to install mysql-server. I’m getting the below error.

```
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
2021-05-29T02:51:22.812281Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2021-05-29T02:51:22.812291Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Error while setting value 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'.
2021-05-29T02:51:22.813552Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

Command used: `sudo apt install mysql-server`

I used the above command after upgrade to Ubuntu20.
I even tried to edit the configuration, but that didn’t help. Below are the contents of /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[mysqld]
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

I found a similar question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296168/mysql-fail-after-ubuntu-20-04-upgrade

Comment: Could you try to write in `mysql.cnf` as following instead `sqlmode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` . Without `"` and according to the [valid values list here?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode)

Comment: Editing my question too. I did, but it didn't work. Below is the content:

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[mysqld]
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37978275/10910692 ?

Answer (score 6):

Thank you @FANO_FN.
This was the line in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` which needed to be corrected. mysql8 doesn't have the value of NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode) anymore.
So, I removed that from the list of values and it started working.

The final values look like below:

`sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`

Comment: Wait, were you trying to use those modes? because commenting it means it's not in use..

Comment: I just wanted to get it working. I now understood why it was erroring out. The value 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER ' is no longer part of myql8

Comment: Super helpful - I had a MySQL update fail when upgrading Ubuntu (to 20.04) and removing NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER got things back on track